# Partial reading of HTTP requests

Tags: http, network-programming

Suppose I have a server (REST) application, which does not need to read fully incoming HTTP requests. Clients may send large HTTP requests of any size but I need only first `X` Kilobytes.

I would like to  read only `X` Kilobytes and immediately close the connection. Does it make sense? Is it *legal* in terms of HTTP? What are alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to read only X Kilobytes and immediately close the connection. Does it make sense?*

Not for a REST-ful application.

*Is it legal in terms of HTTP?*

Yes, technically.  In the HTTP protocol a server response of some kind is always expected for a complete transaction.  This will be experienced by the client as a premature ending of the connection, i.e. an incomplete or aborted transaction.

*What are alternatives?*

What are you trying to accomplish?

If you just want to read the first X bytes of whatever is sent by any client who connects and then not bother to reply at all, then the HTTP protocol is not for you, never mind REST.